# Bash : While & if

Tags: bash, shell

I wrote this command

```
 i=$1
 file=/home/dream/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemAT/data/dico/$i.dico.forme.lemme.txt  
 while  read -r f1 f2 f3 ; do
     if [[ "$f3" = "<unknown>" ]];
     then echo $f2  $f1
     else echo $f3  $f1
     fi
 done < $file
```

I got an error because of the `$i`.
I tested this command on 1 file, but it doesn't work when I tried to use it for 20 files

Comment: everything you say is true.  what is your question?

Comment: *Please* make an effort to learn how to format code in your posts properly. So far, every single question of yours had to be edited to be legible. Have a look at [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I assume the `enter code here` is an artifact of creating the post?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: What do the files contain?

Comment: How are you trying to use it for 20 files? There's no loop that processes multiple files.

Comment: How did you run your script, did you supply a command-line parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to give multiple arguments to the script, you need another loop.

```
for i in "$@"
do
    file=/home/dream/Bureau/ProjetM2_DreemABOUTALEB/data/dico/"$i".dico.forme.lemme.txt  
    while  read -r f1 f2 f3 ; do
        if [[ "$f3" = "<unknown>" ]];
        then echo "$f2  $f1"
        else echo "$f3  $f1"
        fi
    done < "$file"
done
```

Also remember to quote your variables, otherwise you'll run into problems if there's whitespace or wildcard characters in the values.

Comment: I suspect you have CRLF line breaks instead of Unix LF, because you edited the script on Windows. Use `dos2unix` to fix the file.